# Why does SQLite not realize this is a covering index?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE image
(
    capture_time,
    capture_number,

    part_located,

    other_data,
    some_more_data,

    PRIMARY KEY (capture_time, capture_number)
) WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE INDEX image_ix_no_part
    ON image (capture_time, capture_number)
    WHERE NOT part_located;
```

The partial index was specifically created for queries like this one:

```
SELECT capture_time, capture_number FROM image
    WHERE NOT part_located
    ORDER BY capture_time, capture_number;
```

Unfortunately, `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` doesn't mention anything about a covering index, even though this partial index contains all the necessary information. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: It appears partial indexes are never assumed to be covering.

Comment: @CL After playing around a bit, it looks like adding part_located to the indexed columns does make it covering. So SQLite probably only uses the 'WHERE' constraint to determine whether to use the index or not, but doesn't realise it automatically satisfies the 'NOT part_located' part of the query as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround I ended up using:

```
CREATE INDEX image_ix_no_part
    ON image (
        capture_time, capture_number,
        part_located -- Needed for a covering index search.
    )
    WHERE NOT part_located;
```

It needlessly adds a zero to the end of every index entry, but it only takes one byte so it's an acceptable loss.